# Calculator app, making a Cosinus function

Tags: c++, c++builder

How can I make a cosinus function?

[image]

I can't figure out how to do this.

```cpp
number2 = Label1->Caption;
if(number1 != "" && number2 != "" && znak != ""){
    if(znak == "+")
        Label1->Caption = AnsiString(number1.ToDouble() + number2.ToDouble());
    if(znak == "-")
        Label1->Caption = AnsiString(number1.ToDouble() - number2.ToDouble());
    if(znak == "*")
        Label1->Caption = AnsiString(number1.ToDouble() * number2.ToDouble());
    if(znak == "^^")
        Label1->Caption = AnsiString(number1.ToDouble() number2.ToDouble());
    if(znak == "/") {
        if (number2 != "0,0") {
            Label1->Caption = AnsiString(number1.ToDouble() / number2.ToDouble());
        }
        else {
            ShowMessage("Ошибка! Деление на ноль!");
            Label1->Caption = "";
            break;
        }
    }

    number2 = "";
    znak = "";
    number1 = Label1->Caption;
    return;
}
```

Comment: How is the code you show, in any way related to the question concerning cosinus function? Also, please do not post useless images of your screen. When an image clarifies the issue you are asking about, keep it small, and to the point. Consider that many people are using rather small devices, like e.g. phones.

Comment: I BCB once you include `math.h` you got `sin` and `cos` ... beware its in radians so in case you want to convert `ang` from degrees then use `cos(ang*M_PI/180.0)` ...

Answer (score 2):

The sane way is to use [std::cos](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/cos) . If you want to implement your own approximation you should look into [taylor series](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/taylor-series.html), but that's rarely the right thing to do.